# How to create a wavelength animation of a voice recorder app in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, flutter, dart

I am trying to build a clone of the native iOS voice notes-taking application in Flutter. Also, a similar application is available on OxygenOS on the name of 'recorder'. How do I get an auto-scrolling view that will move with an increase in recording time and also showing the dot animation in the form of wavelength as shown in the picture:

[image]

This was one of the [alternatives](https://youtu.be/FE7Vtzq52xg) that I could find which is cool but is there any flutter package/plugin that I can utilize to perform this. If not, can you provide me with an alternative to this problem?

Comment: There's probably no one flutter plugin that'll do it all, but I did find waveform plugins that you could adapt to use: https://pub.dev/packages/wave and https://pub.dev/packages/wave_generator, otherwise you'll have to make this plugin yourself (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen that some projects have been using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_waveforms) - *AudioWave Forms*. It looks interesting.

You may take an eye of it and check if this fulfills your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything so far? You can start exploring with [flutter_ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) to [generate waveform data from audio](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Waveform). It's up to you on what format you'll use for your waveform data. Once you got your data, you can generate waveform graphs in Flutter using [CustomPaint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html). You can check the sample on this [blog post](https://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2019-07-drawing-waveforms-in-flutter/). The waveform data used in the sample is in JSON.